# How to fix the DNS resolution failed in grpc

Tags: python, grpc

I had my client which use gRPC. My problem is that it doesn't compile because of a mistake in the dns that I can't remove. If I comment on the create part then it works (but I have to use the create part):

```
# example_consumer.py
import pika, os, time
import grpc
import garden_pb2_grpc
import garden_pb2

# Access the CLODUAMQP_URL environment variable and parse it (fallback to localhost)

url = os.environ.get('CLOUDAMQP_URL', 'amqp://lay5672')
params = pika.URLParameters(url)
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(params)
channel = connection.channel()  # start a channel
channel.queue_declare(queue='garden')  # Declare a queue
grpcChannel = grpc.insecure_channel('https://')  # connection 
stub = garden_pb2_grpc.GardenServiceStub(grpcChannel)  

my_garden = garden_pb2.Garden(
    id="5d0a61f86e95521de096efb3",
    position=garden_pb2.Garden.Position(lat=1, lng=2),
    size=garden_pb2.Garden.Size(height=10, width=20),
    garden=[],
    userID="5d0a61f86e95521de096efb3"
)

createRequest = garden_pb2.CreateRequest(
    garden=my_garden
)


def garden_process_function(msg):
    print("Received " + str(msg))
    print("This function can do something")
    time.sleep(1)  # delays for 5 seconds
    feature = stub.Create(createRequest)  # je dois appeler avec un objet create request
    return;


# create a function which is called on incoming messages
def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
    garden_process_function(body)


class Server(object):
    @staticmethod
    def receiveMsg():
        # set up subscription on the queue
        channel.basic_consume('garden',
                              callback,
                              auto_ack=True)
        # start consuming (blocks)
        channel.start_consuming()
        connection.close()


class App(object):
    @staticmethod
    def run():
        print('Running...')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    App.run()
    Server.receiveMsg()
```

But I got this error:

```
grpc._channel._Rendezvous: <_Rendezvous of RPC that terminated with:
    status = StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE
    details = "DNS resolution failed"
debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1570759414.997000000","description":"Failed to pick subchannel","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/client_channel.cc","file_line":3876,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1570759414.997000000","description":"Resolver transient failure","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/resolving_lb_policy.cc","file_line":263,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1570759414.997000000","description":"DNS resolution failed","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/resolver/dns/native/dns_resolver.cc","file_line":189,"grpc_status":14,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1570759414.997000000","description":"OS Error","file":"src/core/lib/iomgr/resolve_address_windows.cc","file_line":96,"os_error":"The specified class was not found.\r\n","syscall":"getaddrinfo","wsa_error":10109}]}]}]}
```

What did I do wrong? I don't understand the mistake at all. I'm under windows